# Run one of two different SELECT queries based on declared value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can i run one of two different SELECT queries based on parameter for example.

```
if (x=1)
then
SELECT Product_Name, Pro_ID FROM Store
else
SELECT [Product_Name] FROM [Store] WHERE (Supplier_ID = 3)
```

Comment: You are showing two queries with different columns. Two different things hence. You would usually have an app sending either the first or the second query to the DBMS. If the columns were the same (so both queries would return product_name and pro_id - the second probably returning null for pro_id - in your example), then you could write a query combining the two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the below code will be useful. If I understood you correctly.This code is working fine in SQL Server 2012

```
--Creating a Table.
CREATE TABLE #MyTable 
    (
    Column1 VARCHAR(10), 
    Column2 VARCHAR(10),
    OptionalColumn VARCHAR(10)
    )
--Inserting value to the Table.
INSERT INTO #MyTable
VALUES('Value 1', 'Value 1','Optional Value')

--IF ELSE Logic to desired output.
DECLARE @Check bit 
SET @Check = 0

IF @Check = 1 
    (
    SELECT 
        Column1, 
        Column2
    FROM 
        #MyTable
    )
ELSE
   (
    SELECT 
        Column1, 
        Column2,
        OptionalColumn
    FROM 
        #MyTable
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[IF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)** in following:

```
IF (@x = 1)
BEGIN
   SELECT Product_Name, Pro_ID FROM Store    
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT [Product_Name] FROM [Store] WHERE (Supplier_ID = 3)
END
```

Or shorter way:

```
IF (@x = 1) 
   SELECT Product_Name, Pro_ID FROM Store      
ELSE 
   SELECT [Product_Name] FROM [Store] WHERE (Supplier_ID = 3)
```

Comment: Can't you do it after the `BEGIN` ?

Comment: @sagi I've misunderstood you, what do you mean?